# WP All Import take xml title and use it to get post ID

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, import

I have a job listing site and I am trying to import an XML feed of jobs using WP All Import into custom fields, but in one of the fields on the XML feed it has the company name, I want to take this company name search the companies on the site (which are custom post types I believe) using this title and retrieve the ID back and import the ID into the custom field instead I have been trying this function:

```
function get_page_id($page_name){
    get_page_by_title($page_name, OBJECT, 'noo_company');
    return $page_name->ID;
}
```

and calling the function in the custom field with

```
[get_page_id({companyname[1]})]
```

I can't seem to get anything returning and have been searching for hours and can't seem to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

You failed to actually do anything with the return value of the `get_page_id` function.

```
function get_page_id($page_name){
    $found_post = get_page_by_title($page_name, OBJECT, 'noo_company');
    return $found_post->ID;
}
```

And if you can't guarantee that a post will be found for every possible input value, then this should be written a bit more "defensive", so that it checks whether anything was found, and returns 0 or null instead if not.

Comment: thanks, do you recommend a way to add the defensive feature? also i tried it again with your suggestions with a post title that i know exists and still nothing

Comment: Have you tried this code outside of the import context? Like, put it into a page template somewhere and supply a static page name, and see what result that gets you. (var_dump instead of return.)